# Why does windows 8.1 boot time increase with the presense of more than 50k installed fonts

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, fonts

I test fonts for a living. I have a windows 8.1 computer (yoga 3 pro) with 8gigs of RAM.

I have noticed that after installing all my fonts from my previous machine (windows xp), my boot up time has dramaticlly changed. Specifically the time between windows load and the log-on splash.

Before I was able to boot up in 10 seconds due to my solid state drive. Now it takes around five mins. There is a five min black screen before the log-on splash.

The fonts have already been installed but I am wondering what in the boot sequence is slowed down.

Comment: If I were to hazard to guess.  Windows is attempting to load 50,000 fonts into memory.  I would also guess that it eventually fails to do that.  Windows 10 during the setup procedure only starts the process, then if it is taking to long, will silently continue but still proceed with the rest of the process.

Comment: For 50k fonts you probably want 16gb of RAM to offset that many fonts.  However, windows is still going to load them and slow you down.

Comment: Do you test all 50K fonts at the same time? Perhaps it is best to use a font manager and load in the ones you need after boot, keeping back the minimum to allow your OS to boot quickly.

Comment: capture a boot trace of the normal Windows boot, now add the fonts and capture a new trace and compare them: http://pastebin.com/CYGqRZXE